# Append `<script>` tag to html using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on a slide show where I need to return a portion of HTML with a `<script>` tag and a piece of javascript function in it.I want to add it as I can have multiple slide shows and each one with different properties like transitions,slide speed etc.This function consists the parameters of the slider properties.

```
  return    '<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">'+
                '<div class="">'+
                    '<img id="" class="image mover" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" src="http://localhost/gobiggi_VS_2_2/images/slideShow/slide01.jpg" data-thumb="images/slideShow/thumb/slide01.jpg" alt="" />'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="">'+
                    '<img id="" class="image mover" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" src="http://localhost/gobiggi_VS_2_2/images/slideShow/slide02.jpg" data-thumb="images/slideShow/thumb/slide02.jpg" alt="" />'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="">'+
                    '<img id="" class="image mover" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" src="http://localhost/gobiggi_VS_2_2/images/slideShow/slide03.jpg" data-thumb="images/slideShow/thumb/slide03.jpg" alt="" />'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="">'+
                    '<img id="" class="image mover" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" src="http://localhost/gobiggi_VS_2_2/images/slideShow/slide04.jpg" data-thumb="images/slideShow/thumb/slide04.jpg" alt="" />'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+'<script>$("#slider").nivoSlider({effect: "sliceDown",animSpeed: 500,pauseTime: 3000,startSlide: 0,controlNavThumbs: true,controlNavThumbsFromRel:true, pauseOnHover: true,manualAdvance: false});</script>';
```

**The function inside setTimeout is the one I need to store inside the HTML**
I tried to achieve it by storing it in a variable and attaching it inside the `setTimeout()`.I used `.toString()` and `.append()` `.html` `.text` but **the script directly runs or executes instead of storing it in the html** structure.How can I just store the function inside the script tag in the HTML structure?

Comment: `setTimeout()` doesn't wait for other code. If code is not done yet, or has a bit of delay the code can collide.

Comment: jQuery evaluates any script tags in your HTML, then discard them.

Comment: @SalmanA Can you suggest a way how can I store it to the HTML as I need to execute the function once the user publishes his website. **FYI:**I want it to be stored along with the html to the database,becoz this is a website builder kind of application.User can save and publish it on the web,so after publish I need to have the function or properties stored somewhere in the html structure so that the slideshow works.And each instance of slideshow may have different parameters set against it,so I cannot have a common `<script>` tag in the page

Answer (score 1):

If you want the contents of the script tag to be stored as a function, you need to give that function a name. Simply enclose it all in a `function setSlideShowTimeout() { setTimeout(function … ); };`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.`setTimeout`was added for testing.What we are trying is to save the entire `<script>` tag with the function properties in the html and have it saved to the database.**EDITED the question for it.Please have a look**

Comment: the id #slider would be attached dynamically for each slider

Answer (score 1):

your `setTimeout` function is incorrect..

```
 '<script>setTimeout(function slideShow(){$("#slider")......</script>';
                      //------^^^^^^^^---here you are creating a function `slideShow`
```

it should be

```
'<script>setTimeout(function(){$("#slider")......</script>';
```

**OR**

```
 function slideShow(){
      $("#slider").nivoSlider({
            effect: "sliceDown",
            animSpeed: 500,
            pauseTime: 3000,
            startSlide: 0,
            controlNavThumbs: true,
            controlNavThumbsFromRel:true, 
            pauseOnHover: true,
            manualAdvance: false
      })
  }

 setTimeout(slideShow,100);
```

and i don't think you need to add this in return.. add this in your main page.. and it should work

Comment: `setTimeout`was added for testing.What we are trying is to save the entire `<script>` tag with the function properties in the html and have it saved to the database.**EDITED the question for it.Please have a look**

Comment: the id `#slider` would be attached dynamically for each slider.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a name with a function expression, it's optional (though usually omitted).

Comment: why don't you store the script in another div without the `<script>` tag , with `display:none`, give it an id... and take it out when need....have you tried that too ??

Comment: I want it to be stored along with the html to the database,becoz this is a website builder kind of application.User can **save and publish** it on the web,so after publish I need to have the **function or properties** stored somewhere in the html structure so that the slideshow works.And each instance of slideshow may have different parameters set against it,so I cannot have a common `<script>` tag in the page

Comment: I cannot use `display:none` or any other function when the user publishes the site.I want to have a function at the top which will be called by all sliders with different parameters.But currently instead of getting stored it executes while the user is working on the page itself and doesn't persist to database.